# all file metadata is unset

Tags: centos, permissions

I was renaming files and I mistakenly moved a directory. When I moved it back to its original name all the file informations was unset.  It looked like this:

```
theserver:/web % ls -l site
total 0
?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? admin
?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? ajax
?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? common
?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? contacts.php
?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? css
?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? error
?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? error.php
?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? forms
?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? images
```

This almost caused me a heart attack!  Fortunately, it appears to fix itself if I `chmod 755 site`. So, in the interest of understanding what happened:

- Why does the filesystem seem to lose track of the info?
- Why does it all come back when the parent directory permissions are reset?
- How is it that I can change permissions on a file of unknown ownership when I am logged in as a regular user?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you believe that you can change permissions on a file of unknown ownership? What have you done and what were the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have read access to a directory then you can see the entry names. The other metadata (type, size, owner, permissions and so on) is readable only to those users who have the execute right for the directory. If you had executed `ls -l site` as root then you would have received a normal directory listing.

In other words: The file system has not lost track of anything. It just denied you this information.